# How do I lookup a key/symbol based on which Regex match?

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I am extracting files from a zip archive in Ruby using RubyZip, and I need to label files based on characteristics of their filenames:

Example:
I have the following hash:

```
labels = {
   :data_file=>/.\.dat/i, 
   :metadata=>/.\.xml/i,
   :text_location=>/.\.txt/i
 }
```

So, I have the file name of each file in the zip, let's say an example is

```
filename = 382582941917841df.xml
```

Assume that each file will match only one Regex in the `labels` hash, and if not it doesn't matter, just choose the first match. (In this case the regular expressions are all for detecting extensions, but it could be to detect any filename mask like DSC****.jpg for example.

I am doing this now:

```
label_match =~ labels.find {|key,value| filename =~ value}

---> label_match = [:metadata, /.\.xml/]

label_sym = label_match.nil? ? nil: label_match.first
```

So this works fine, however doesn't seem very Ruby-like. Is there something I am missing to clean this up nicely?

Answer (score 2):

A `case when` does this effortlessly:

```
filename = "382582941917841df.xml"

category = case filename 
  when /.\.dat/i ; :data_file
  when /.\.xml/i ; :metadata
  when /.\.txt/i ; :text_location
end

p category # => :metadata ; nil if nothing matched
```

Comment: This is a good answer, unfortunately I may need to add to these programmatically which rules out a case statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing it backwards and the hard way. Ruby makes it easy to get the extension of a file, which then makes it easy to map it to something.

Starting with something like:

```
FILENAMES = %w[ foo.bar foo.baz 382582941917841df.xml DSC****.jpg]

FILETYPES = {
  '.bar' => 'bar',
  '.baz' => 'baz',
  '.xml' => 'metadata',
  '.dat' => 'data',
  '.jpg' => 'image'
}

FILENAMES.each do |fn|
  puts "#{ fn } is a #{ FILETYPES[File.extname(fn)] } file"
end
# >> foo.bar is a bar file
# >> foo.baz is a baz file
# >> 382582941917841df.xml is a metadata file
# >> DSC****.jpg is a image file
```

[`File.extname`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html#method-c-extname) is built into Ruby. The [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html) class contains many similar methods useful for finding out things about files known by the OS and/or tearing apart file paths and file names so it's a really good thing to become very familiar with.

It's also important to understand that an improperly written regexp, such as `/.\.dat/i` can be the source of a lot of pain. Consider these:

```
'foo.xml.dat'[/.\.dat/] # => "l.dat"
'foo.database.20010101.csv'[/.\.dat/] # => "o.dat"
```

- Are the files *really* "data" files?
- Why is the character in front of the delimiting `.` important or necessary?
- Do you really want to slow your code using unanchored regexp patterns when a method, such as `extname` will be faster and less maintenance?

Those are things to consider when writing code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would I write that regex more correctly. With regard to the file extensions I wrote this "In this case the regular expressions are all for detecting extensions, but it could be to detect any filename mask like DSC****.jpg for example"

Comment: So using the extension only doesn't suit the use case

Comment: Then what is the *full* specification you are using to determine a filetype? As is, it's unexplained what parts of the name are significant. For example, *why* do you capture the character preceding the `'.'`? Normally the extension of a file's name is the determinant for the file type. (Even though extensions shouldn't be used that way since they might not even exist.) Is `****` significant in a `.jpg` file or is it sufficient that it's a "DSC" JPEG file?

Comment: The reg. exp's are passed in from another application all together. So the *full* specification is that there is a number of label -> regex pairs, and the reg expressions could be anything provided that they don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `nil` to indicate the label when there is no match, consider using another symbol like `:unknown`.

Then you can do:

```
labels = {
  :data_file=>/.\.dat/i, 
  :metadata=>/.\.xml/i,
  :text_location=>/.\.txt/i,
  :unknown=>/.*/
}
label = labels.find {|key,value| filename =~ value}.first
```

Comment: I am under the impression that hashes in Ruby are not guaranteed to have an order, so surely this would then possibly result in a known file being categorised an unknown?

Comment: Also, I will still need to reject the unknown files

Comment: @JohnLinux Hashes maintain insertion order since version 1.9.

Comment: As mentioned, Hashes do maintain insertion order so this will work fine. What you do with the `:unknown` files is up to you of course. Assuming your rejection process is checking for `nil` just check for `unknown` instead.